# How to format rails JSON with a line break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, kendo-ui, line-breaks

I am working on a rails app using kendo UI, I am creating a json object to populate a table within a table cell I need their to be line breaks so I am trying to include a line break when I set the json but it is not working.  Is it possible to add a line break with a value when you are creating the json object?  Below is what I have tried.

```
@all_data = campaign_data.map do |campaign|
  { :name => campaign.name, 
    :status => "closed", 
    :channels => "TV" + "\n" + "Radio"
  }
end
```

What I want to have outputed in the table cell is:

```
  TV
  Radio
```

Comment: If this data is for the contents of a tag, then you'll need to use an html `<br>` tag instead of a text-file-style linebreak.

Comment: so... :channels => "TV" + "<br>" + "Radio"?  This does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add a CSS definition in order to treat `white-space` as `pre`. Something like:

```
.ob-break {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

And then template the cell where you want to use this as:

```
columns: [
    ...    
    { field: "User", template: "<span class='ob-break'>#= User #</span>" }
]
```

or you can use it for every cell and then do something like:

```
#grid td {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Where `grid` is the identifier of the table.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/uqFdT/2/

**NOTE**: As far as I understand `<br/>` is intentionally disabled in order to prevent [HTML script injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#HTML_Script_Injection).